# Spring Cloud Gateway routes to Tomcat AJP

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

When Tomcat AJP port is opened as 8090 like test.domain.com:8090,

it's not working when I use uri as belows in Spring Cloud Gateway routes section.

```
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: efss_gateway
          uri: http://test.domain.com:8090
          predicates:
            - Path=/gtw/**
```

Is there another way?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it's not working"?